# Typehead JS is not working on multiple inputs with same classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typehead

The problem I'm facing is related with Invoicing system. There is one row exists by default but if there are more than one products then user can **Add New Item** which adds the new row with jQuery append function.

Invoicing system has few Inputs one of them is Item Name which autocomplete by Typehead JS.

Code of Predefined Row

```html
<tbody id="TableBody">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 220px">
      <input type="text" class="form-control Item" name="Item" id="Item" placeholder="Nombre del producto" required autocomplete="off">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" name="QTV" min="1" name="QTV" id="QTV" class="form-control text-right" placeholder="00" required>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input step="2" type="number" class="form-control text-right" min="1" id="Rate" placeholder="0.00" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input step="any" id="Disc" name="Disc" type="number" min="0" name="" class="form-control text-right" placeholder="00">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="SubTotal" class="form-control text-right" id="Total" placeholder="Total" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger DelRow">Delete</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Code to Add new Row

```html
$('#AddNewItem').click(function() { $('#TableBody').append(`
<tr>
  <td style='width: 220px'>
    <input type='text' class='form-control Item' name='Item' id='Item' placeholder='Nombre del producto' required autocomplete='off'>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type='number' name='QTV' min='1' name='QTV' id='QTV' class='form-control text-right' placeholder='00' required>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input step='2' type='number' class='form-control text-right' min='1' id='Rate' placeholder='0.00' readonly>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input step='any' id='Disc' name='Disc' type='number' min='0' name='' class='form-control text-right' placeholder='00'>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type='text' name='SubTotal' class='form-control text-right' id='Total' placeholder='Total' readonly>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger DelRow">Delete</button>
  </td>
</tr>
`); });
```

Code to show Auto suggestions

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.Item').typeahead({
  source:  function (query, process) {
  return $.get('FetchItem.php?Item', { query: query }, function (data) {    
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
    return process(data);
   });
  },
 });
});
```

I just wanted to show suggestions on all the additional appended fields. 
Any help would be much appreciated, Thank you

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckSRt.png)

Comment: One more thing I have noticed is that it works fine when I write the Input code twice in actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afterall, I got the solution to my answer.

I was using jQuery document load function which was not working on the appended rows.

So instead of `$(document).ready(function() {` I just used `$('.TableBody').on("click", ".Item", function() {` and it worked.